# Spring getBean(Class<T> interfaceToCreate, Object... args) method is missing?

Tags: spring

I was trying to create factory class for my spring beans

```
public interface MyBean implements TBean{}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class MyBeanImpl implements MyBean{
   public MyBeanImpl(Request request){//..}
}

@Component
public class MyFactory {
    public <T extends TBean> T createbean(Class<T> interfaceToCreate, Object... args) {
        return (T)AppContext.getApplicationContext().getBean(interfaceToCreate, args);
    }
}
```

method `AppContext.getApplicationContext()` returns [ApplicationContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html) object

here I should be be able to create a spring bean like:

```
@Autowired
protected MyFactory factory;

Request myRequest;
void somemethod(){
    factory.createbean(MyBean.class, myRequest)
}
```

but [BeanFactory](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html)  does not expose any method like: `getBean(Class<T> clazz, Object... args)` And I do not have default constructor for `MyBeanImpl` class

Does anyone know how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that in two steps. The `ListableBeanFactory` provides a method `String[] getBeanNamesForType(Class<?> type)`. Once you got the bean names for your type, you can invoke the `BeanFactory.getBean(String name, Object... args)`.

Comment: That does work, we can survive with this,but spring could provide this: `getBean(Class<T> clazz, Object… args)` signature. Thanks for the answer